# How to handle empty anchors in a IOS webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, anchor

I have transformed a website into an IOS webapp, works perfect, but the only thing is that if I press a empty anchor (see code below) the page goes to the top or bottom of the page, this only happens in the webapp, and not if I use safari on the iPad. I **cant** replace all empty links so is there an solution for this?

basic link

```
<a href="#">some link</a>
```

code that will work is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">works</a>
```

**EDIT: found the issue, if you are using an IOS webapp if will open new links in safari, therefor i used the prevent script from the mobile boilerplate https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate.**

Comment: try onclick="return false" with it

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false" > may it works</a>
```

Comment: This is double, as void doesn't fire the anchor, so will the onclick ;-).....so you dont need to use the onclick

Comment: onclick fire first than void and some time ios.js creates problem with void that`s why i have posted this , have you tried ?

Comment: ah okay. Not tried, and not going to try, as i cant change the html code it self, if i could i would use the void it self because this works.